# Laravel10,vue3の連携ができません

Tags: laravel, vue.js

現在Laravel10、Vue3を使用してSNSのようなものを作ろうとしています。
Laravelで作ったものをvueファイルで表示をさせようしています。
ですが、リンクはつながっており、画面自体にエラーは出ないのですが下記のようなエラーがF12で出てきます。
エラーが出る原因なども分かっておらず、解決策も分からないため、解決策または、おすすめの参考サイトなどがあれば教えてほしいです。

あと、初めてこのような質問サイトを使うため、その他必要なものや、こういうものは書いていたほうがいいよなどというものがあれば教えてください。
[image: 画像はエラーの画像です]

Comment: コードやエラーメッセージは画面キャプチャではなく、文字のまま質問に貼り付けてください。